# Full recursive history for all check-ins in entire folder

Tags: svn

I seem to be having the greatest difficulty finding out how to generate the report I need using SVN's native command line options.

I want to generate a report showing complete check-in history for every file in the repo (recursive).  I am ultimately looking for something like the table below that can be output to a flat file for import into a database or Excel sheet.  I want to see the file sizes for each so that I can calculate differences between revisions (or perhaps there is even an option to include the size diff in the report).

```
Username   File                   Date                  Size
jimbob     repo/project/file.cs   2016/09/12 12:30:00   1,400
jimbob     repo/project/file.cs   2016/09/07 11:00:00   1,200
jimbob     repo/project/file.cs   2016/09/01 13:30:00   850
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not without some scripting as SVN saves the revisions not per file-item but as changesets(multiple files changing in same commit).

Your report makes sense in an CVS or sourcesafe style of repo.
In SVN you can easily get a list of all revisions, with all modified files but not history for each single file. For this you need to go over the filetree in SVN (and depending on showing deleted/renamed items you may need to go over all filetrees in all revisions, or make a smarter analysis).

Comment: It appears you're right.  I've begun exploring SharpSVN which, so far, is giving me all the modular functionality I need.